# How can I perform calculation on the numeric portion of a sting in a mysql query

Tags: mysql

Due to some restrictions by my client, I need to do this thing within a single mysql query.

I have a `varchar` field, with value like: `3,050 wheels`
I have another `integer` field, with value: `2`

I need the query to return me `6,100 wheels`.

I can probably use `CONVERT` to convert the 3,050 to number, but I don't know how to find the index of `" "`, moreover the output again needs to be formatted with a comma and concatenated back with the string(non-numeric) portion.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to select the appropriate part of the string, and `FORMAT` to convert the number back to a string.

All the functions are described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).

```
CONCAT(FORMAT(CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(f, ' ', 1), UNSIGNED) * g, 0),
       ' ',
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(f,' ',-1))
```

Comment: Thank you, one more question, how would I handle more than one words? like: `3,050 wheels and spikes`? If I just say `-1` as index, it will just grab `spikes`, and I cannot be sure how many words there would be

Comment: Then you might need to use `LOCATE` and `SUBSTR` to get the word part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast):

```
SELECT  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1, ' ', -1) AS UNSIGNED)*field2 as result,  FROM tableName ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
CONCAT( FORMAT( CAST( REPLACE( LEFT( field1, locate( ' ', field1 )-1 ), ',', '' ) AS UNSIGNED ) * field2, 0 ),
        MID( field1, LOCATE( ' ', field1 )))
```

It should re-append any amount of text after the initial numeric value in `field1`.  So `3,500 wheels and spikes` should become `7,000 wheels and spikes` if `field2` contains `2`.

Answer (score 0):

To check if number is there in the field then use [MySQL Regular Expression Method](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), to find index you can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and you can proceed with further calculation, e.g

```
SELECT CONVERT(
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,",",1),
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,",",-1), " ", 1)
             ), UNSIGNED) AS NO
FROM table_name
WHERE field REGEXP '[0-9]';
```

Hope this will work for you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
    select 
    concat( convert(substring_index(fieldName, ' ', 1 ), decimal) * intField,
    ',', substr(fieldName, length(substring_index(fieldName, ' ', 1))+1)) 
     as yourField
    from tableName
```